# ArgumentError: Unknown migration version "5.2"; expected one of "4.2", "5.0", "5.1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, carrierwave

I've installed CKEditor(WYSIWYG text editor) in my rails application and I want to use it in uploading images, but after running this command 
 `rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave` am getting the following migration errors...

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Unknown migration version "5.2"; expected one of "4.2", "5.0", "5.1"
```

I've tried using `rake db:migrate` command but the error still occurs.

This is the code am using to load ckeditor in `#app/assets/javascripts/application.js` directory:

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

I expect the migration to run successfully. Where is the problem?

Comment: Seems like you have a pending migration created with 5.2 but you are using rails version 5..1

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the problem by going into migration for creating ck_editor and replaced


`class CreateCkeditorAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]`


to


`class CreateCkeditorAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]`

The file is located at `db/migrate/<time_stamp>_create_ckeditor_assets.rb`

Answer (score 5):

Try replace

```
ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
```

to

```
ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
```

in a migration script, and run migration again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I replaced version number as you said and now am able to run the migration.